# how to get the Google analytics client ID

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

When you are creating a new instance of analytics.js by running

`ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-Y', {'cookieDomain': 'none'});`

GA creates a unique client Id.
I want to fetch this id and use it for my own purposes, 
but I can find only [setter](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#clientId) for this parameter but can't find any getter method to get it.

GA send it later in a parameter called `&cid=123123.232323`

Does anyone knows how do I get it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the client ID when sending tracking data to google analytics via the measurement protocol?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14227331/what-is-the-client-id-when-sending-tracking-data-to-google-analytics-via-the-mea)

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Google does have some [documentation on getting the client id](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/domains#getClientId).

Looks like this:

```
ga(function(tracker) {
  var clientId = tracker.get('clientId');
});
```

I've used this before, too:

```
ga.getAll()[0].get('clientId');
```

**EDIT**:
If you have more than one tracker on the page, it may be probable that at index 0 there is not the one you want, so an alternative function should be the following:

```
function() {
  try {
    var trackers = ga.getAll();
    var i, len;
    for (i = 0, len = trackers.length; i < len; i += 1) {
      if (trackers[i].get('trackingId') === "ID-PROPERTY") {
        return trackers[i].get('clientId');
      }
    }
  } catch(e) {}  
  return 'false';
}
```

where ID-PROPERTY is the id of your Property (i.e. UA-XXXXX-XX).

Comment: So I'm assuming we need to add some kind of analytics JS library to our  web project? Can we then send this value to the back end for Java integration in this Java code? https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/google-analytics

Comment: Hi @Blexy, any idea why the GA documentation function doesn't work? Using getAll does thankfully. Just curious why the other method doesn't return anything though.

Comment: @DougFirr seems like you are using **synchronous** syntax when calling _getAll_ and analytics library has not being initialized and processed the queue yet. So there is no tracker at index 0 at that time.
Try using **async** syntax like `ga(function(tracker) { /* Your getter code */});`

Comment: I'm interested for **synchronous code**. Is `ga.getAll()[0].get('clientId');` documented and assured to be valid in a few months/years or something that could be modified soon?

Comment: Any reasons why it is not working for me ?! I used this script exactly.

Answer (score 36):

Although the author explicitly said he is using Javascript, others (like me) may be searching for a way to get this information from the server-side, like PHP.

For both: GA4 and UA, I found that you can easily check for the _ga cookie, which looks like:

```
_ga=GA1.3.475128143.1522318100
```

In the exemple above, the user id is "475128143.1522318100".

So, in PHP I can fetch it quickly as:

```
$gaUserId = preg_replace("/^.+\.(.+?\..+?)$/", "\\1", @$_COOKIE['_ga']);
```

You can also use Javascript to retrieve the cookie in a single line, without using ga() functions:

```
var gaUserId = document.cookie.match(/_ga=(.+?);/)[1].split('.').slice(-2).join(".")
```

This is working for me.

Comment: downvoted, sorry!  google analytics documentation specifically says _not_ to access their cookie via browser API as their cookie may change.  instead, use the provided-for APIs to get the client ID.

Comment: @BenjaminHoffman Can you please share the reference for this?

Comment: it's all over their documentation. but here is just one instance. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cookies-user-id#getting_the_client_id_from_the_cookie

Comment: @BenjaminHoffman Their documentation only shows the Javascript version.

Comment: @BenjaminHoffman sometimes this isn't a practical option and a solution similar to the one shown in the answer above is useful

Comment: From Google documentation: "You should not directly access the cookie analytics.js sets, as the cookie format might change in the future. Instead, developers should use the readyCallback to wait until analytics.js is loaded, and then get the clientId value stored on the tracker." - https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cookies-user-id#getClientId

Answer (score 6):

First create the Google Analytics **ga** object to create a **tracker** object, by passing it a **"Ready callback"** function, then use the tracker to call other methods.

The **ga()** command queue provides an interface for doing almost everything you need to do with the analytics.js library.

**"function(tracker)"** is a callback function to be invoked when the analytics library is fully loaded and ready to be interacted with. The function is invoked with the default tracker object as it first argument. If no default tracker has been created, the first argument is/will return undefined.

Note: when the callback function is invoked, all ga object methods are available for use. Including the one you want **tracker.get('clientId')**

Replace the **UA-XXXXX-Y** in the code below with your UA code from Google Analytics.

```
// Queues a tracker object for creation.
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');

// Once the tracker has been created, log the
// client ID to the console.
ga(function(tracker) {
  console.log(tracker.get('clientId'));
  /* Your other code here */
});
```

Alternatively for lines 1 & 2, use the code below to create a named tracker.

```
// Queues a named tracker object for creation.
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto', 'myTracker');
```

Official Google documentation: [Cookies and User Identification](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cookies-user-id#getClientId)

Comment: I think your first code block has one too many }'s (there's one on the same line as the "other code here" comment and one on the next line).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Google Tag Manager, you can use User-Defined Variable -> Variable type: "1st-Party Cookie" -> Cookie Name = _ga. Let's call it "GA Cookie". It will store value like this GA.1.1.123.123.

To cut the "GA.1.1", make another User-Defined Variable -> Variable Type: "Custom JavaScript" and write a simple JS function:

```
function() {
    var pattern = "GA1.1.";
    var id = {{GA Cookie}}.substr(pattern.length);
    return id;
}
```

It is not always "GA1.1", but still it has 5 signs. You can use different variable like var length = 5, but as for me, it looks like a kind of magic number.

Comment: I agree with working with the cookies because the `ga.getAll` method doesn't work with GA4, and the supported method for GA4 is asynchronous, but I would do something different with the string: instead of relying on the length of the pattern I would split on the "." and remove the first elements, like this: `{{GA Cookie}}.split('.').slice(2).join('.');`

Answer (score -1):

```
ga((tracker) => {
  console.log(tracker.get('trackingId'));
});
```