# Can I use a GCLID to generate a page view as if it came from the original owner of that GCLID

Tags: google-analytics, tracking, google-ads-api

I've been looking into offline tracking of google analytics goals. I want to implement this in a similar way to how call tracking companies do and I'm guessing the GCLID is the answer.

If I store the GCLID of every visitor that comes to our website in the database alongside some info about their session and then identify their session at a later date as one that produced an offline goal, can I then generate a goal from that?

My thinking is that if I had a button in our CRM system that when I click it opens up an invisible iframe that links to **mysite.com/goalurl.html?gclid=xxx** then analytics on that page would track a goal on that page but attribute it to the original click that the other user made on our PPC advert. Theoretically I could do this 10 times in a row for 10 different sessions and they would all be tracked as if the 10 original owners of those GCLIDs has visited the goal page, right?

Am i missing something here? Would this not work because Google would spot that they all came from the same IP address, or because I would have the same GA cookie on my machine? Or does Gogole not care about any of that?

Any help would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it works with the gclid but would also be interested in the answer.

Besides that, a possible solution is to store the [Analytics client ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20053949/how-to-get-the-google-analytics-client-id) in your own database and, whenever there is a conversion, sending that conversion data (referencing the recorded client ID) directly from your server to Analytics by using the [Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/).

Exactly this topic is a case study in the book "[Google Analytics Breakthrough: From Zero to Business Impact](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-1119144019.html)".