# Get user_pseudo_id from firebase client sdk?

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

In the Firebase Analytics, `user_pseudo_id` is automatically log into bigquery. But, I want to get this value in the firebase client sdk (ex: android, ios sdk) to specify user. 
I found on docs of firebase but couldnt found any reference about this issue of my. Have any suggest to get it?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just found it, it is [documented here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.html#getAppInstanceId()). I also tested that it returns values that I can find in the BigQuery `user_pseudo_id` column.

Example for android:

```java
    FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this).getAppInstanceId().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<String> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                String user_pseudo_id = task.getResult();
            }
        }
    });
```

And for web I used the next snippet (tested on Feb 10th, 2023, I got the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50070138/2469583)):

```
var gaUserId = document.cookie.match(/_ga=(.+?);/)[1].split('.').slice(-2).join(".")
```

I am not sure about IOS but it may be [this one](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseanalytics/api/reference/Classes/Analytics#appinstanceid).