# Getting client ID from GA4 to hidden fields within forms

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, clientid

I want to extract `client_id` for a visit from google analytics and send it to hidden fields within the application forms. I know in Universal Analytics, we can extract it from ga cookie. But how about Google Analytics 4? Do I need to extract it from GA4 API?

Answer (score 2):

If I may add: GA4 does use the same cookie as UA, but the most upvoted method to extract the client ID from the link mentioned by @BNazaruk will not work for GA4.

The method `ga.getAll()[0].get('clientId');` relies on the UA tracker and will **not** work when only GA4 is available on the page.

Of course you can still read it from the `_ga` cookie as other answers suggest.

Answer (score 1):

GA4 uses the same cookie for client id as GA3. The same old answers apply very well to GA4: [how to get the Google analytics client ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20053949/how-to-get-the-google-analytics-client-id)

Not marking this as duplicate because the old question does reference GA4, but I will try and edit the old question and answer to include GA4 there.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming and considering you have access to the Web Page where the application form is.

In the below HTML code, the javascript function **getCookie** returns the cookie value for the given cookie name.

**main** functions fill the hidden input field based on the name i.e _ga here.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Getting client ID from GA4 to hidden fields within forms</title>
    <script>
        function getCookie(name) {
            const value = `; ${document.cookie}`;
            const parts = value.split(`; ${name}=`);
            if (parts.length === 2) return parts.pop().split(';').shift();
        }
        function main() {
            var hiddenFields = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=hidden], input[type=text]");
            for (var i = 0; i < hiddenFields.length; i++) {
                var param = getCookie(hiddenFields[i].name);
                if (param) document.getElementsByName(hiddenFields[i].name)[0].value = param;
            }
        }
        setTimeout(function () { main() }, 3000);
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <input type="hidden" name="_ga">
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found this great article trying to do the same:
https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/google-analytics-client-id/#find
which shows how to use the GTAG to extract different fields:
https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/gtagjs/reference#get

regarding the extraction of the client id from GA4, you can do it with the following code:

```
gtag('get', 'G-XXXXXX', 'client_id', function(clientId) {console.log(clientId)})
```

In case you are using google tag manger to implement GA4, you will also need to add the following code to support getting the client_id (from the docs, it looks like it should work on UA also):

```
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
```