# GA4 user_pseudo_id via api

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I want to extract user_pseudo_id from the api. I understand this would need to be set as a custom dimension but struggling with how to do that. I've seen a number of posts online suggesting to extract the client_id similar to how it was done with UA, but a response to this post
[Getting client ID from GA4 to hidden fields within forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70017973/getting-client-id-from-ga4-to-hidden-fields-within-forms)
suggests that only works on pages where there is a UA tracker and won't work when only GA4 is available.

An alternative is to use the _ga cookie, but this advice from google says not to use that:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cookies-user-id#getting_the_client_id_from_the_cookie

So are there any other ways to get the information I'm after? Would prefer to not have to use big query.

Comment: Are you trying to send the user_pseudo_id as a hidden field in your conversion forms?