# Google Analytics in iOS Embedded Framework conflicts with hosting app?

Tags: objective-c, google-analytics, measurement-protocol

I am building an iOS 8 Embedded Framework which will be available to our clients to integrate into their own apps.  I need to track events occurring within the code of the framework, so I have added the google analytics sdk to the framework.

However, if our client is also using the google analytics framework, I run into duplicate symbol erros.

As a workaround, I have use the [Google Analytics Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/), and built the url myself for tracking events.

It was working for a while, but then stopped - I believe the issue had something to do with the Anonymous client Id parameter which needs to be properly generated unique for each device (I was using a constant value being sent every time to google's servers) ? I think?

Do I need an objective-c equivalent of [creating the anonymous client id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14227331/what-is-the-client-id-when-sending-tracking-data-to-google-analytics-via-the-mea)?

I've also had a look at a [Cocoa Wrapper for Google Analytics Measurement Protocol](https://github.com/Coppertino/AnalyticEverything) but its a bit outdated, and unfinished.

How do I handle this properly and professionally? I need to track google events without causing a headache for hosting applications of my framework?