# Measurement Protocol hits without cId

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce, measurement-protocol

I'm tracking my eCommerce site with Google Analytics and I'm using Googles Measurement Protocol to track offline payments. When a order is made, I save the client id from the cookie with the order. If a customer has something to prevent tracking, I still want to track the eCommerce purchase.

**What cId should I set for those customers?**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about coding, but this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14227331/what-is-the-client-id-when-sending-tracking-data-to-google-analytics-via-the-mea

Comment: I don't know how I should set a  variable.. I guess it is about coding. I've already read the linked topic, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

You can set any arbitrary number of string as client id and the tracking will report hits. But of course an arbitrary client id might not be usable to aggregate hits into sessions, an will not  connect the hits from the measurement protocol to the hits from the web session (so you will lose the traffic source among other things).

Also the Google Analytics TOS state that you must not circumvent privacy features like e.g. an opt-out, so this might violate the terms of service.